# Make openweathermap api contents print in the console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

According to the error I saw when I inspected the code, it has to be in this http format so I cannot change it. I'm trying to figure out how to console log this entire api document.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=92407,us&appid=MY KEY GOES HERE YES I KNOW I HAVE TO ADD THE KEY", false);
xhr.send();

console.log(xhr.statusText);
```

Comment: Do you want to print the response? You can use `xhr.responseText` in console.log

Comment: It's in Json format

Comment: jesus christ thank you!

Comment: Next time please google your details first!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to console the API response. To do that you have to use on **readystatechange** method. Try using this code snippet

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     console.log(this.responseText);
    }
```